Comparison of two crossing number inequalities
Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. The crossing number of $G$, denoted by $cr(G)$, is the minimum number of crossings in a planar embedding of $G$. In the book of Bondy and Murty (Graduate Textbook in Mathematics 244), there are two different lower bounds for the crossing number:

$cr(G) \ge m - 3n + 6$ if $n \ge 3$. (Exercise 10.3.1.)
$cr(G) \ge \frac{m^3}{64n^2}$ if $m \ge 4n$. (This is called the Crossing Lemma, Lemma 13.1)

The authors say, "The Crossing Lemma is much stronger than the first inequality." Without explanation, this is not that obvious to me. And the proofs of these two inequalities are not trivial.

In my understanding, if you take $m = \Theta(n^{1 + \epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, then the first lower bound is asymptotically $\Theta(n^{1 + \epsilon})$ while the second one is $\Theta(n^{1 + 3 \epsilon})$, which might be the difference. Also, this is in general true if $m = \Theta(n f(n))$ for some nontrivial $f(n)$, e.g., $m = \Theta(n \log n)$

Proof of First Inequality:
Consider a planar embedding of $G$ with $cr(G)$ crossings, and a spanning planar subgraph $H$ of $G$ with maximum possible number of edges. Then we have $e(H) \le 3n - 6$ since $H$ is planar. For every edge in $E(G) \setminus E(H)$, it crosses at least one edge of $H$, otherwise, it can be added to $H$, which contradicts the maximality of $|E(H)|$. Such crossings between $E(G) \setminus E(H)$ and $E(H)$ are distinct. Therefore, there are at least $|E(G) \setminus E(H)| = m - |E(H)| \ge m - 3n + 6$ crossings.
Proof of the Crossing Lemma: (The following proof can be found in Bondy and Murty's book)
Consider a planar embedding of $G$ with $cr(G)$ crossings. Let $S$ be a random vertex subset choosing each vertex independently with probability $p$. Let $H = G[S]$, i.e., the subgraph induced by $H$.
Let $X,Y,Z$ be the number of vertices of $H$, the number of edges of $H$, and the crossings of $H$, respectively. Then we have $$ Z \ge cr(H) \ge Y - 3X + 6 \ge Y - 3X$$
and $$ \mathbb{E}[Z] \ge \mathbb{E}[Y] - 3\mathbb{E}[X]$$
Note that, $\mathbb{E}[X] = pn$, $\mathbb{E}[Y] = p^2m$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z] = p^4 cr(G)$, since each vertex has probability $p$ to present, each edge has probability $p^2$ to present, and each crossing, determined by two edges, has probability $p^4$ to present, respectively.
Therefore, $p^4 cr(G) \ge p^2 m - 3pn$ and
$$ cr(G) \ge \frac{pm - 3n}{p^3}$$
Let $p = \frac{4n}m$, we obtain $cr(G) \ge \frac{m^3}{64n^2}$.
Remark: If $m \ge \frac92 n$, we can let $p = \frac{9n}{2m}$ and obtain a slightly better constant factor: $cr(G) \ge \frac4{243} \frac{m^3}{n^2}$.
Comparison of two inequalities:
If the graph $G$ is "not very sparse", say $m = cn^k$ for some $c > 0$ and $k>1$, then the Crossing Lemma gives a better bound:
$$cr(G) \ge \frac{c^3}{64} n^{3k-2} \gg m - 3n + 6 = cn^k - 3n + 6$$
for sufficiently large $n$.
If the graph $G$ is "very sparse", say $m = cn$ for some $c \ge 4$, then the Crossing Lemma gives a better bound if $\frac{c^3}{64} \ge c-3$, where $\frac{c^3}{64} - c + 3 = \frac1{64} (c-4)(c + 2 + \sqrt{52} )(c + 2 - \sqrt{52})$.
Therefore, if $c \ge \sqrt{52} - 2 \approx 5.211$, then the Crossing Lemma gives the better bound; if $4 \ge c < \sqrt{52} - 2$, then $m - 3n + 6$ gives the better bound.
In conclusion, it is not always true that the Crossing Lemma is stronger, but in most cases, especially for graphs that are dense enough, the Crossing Lemma is stronger.

Note that we can easily adapt the crossing inequality to be strictly better than the easy bound by bootstrapping the whole $m−3n+6$ inequality in the proof.
